# How to extract the last 3 element in a sentence for each row in a dataframe?

Tags: r, regex, string, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(matrix.unlist.all_dates...nrow...230..byrow...T. = c(
"Willem F. Duisenberg, President of the European Central Bank, Christian Noyer,  Vice-President of the European Central Bank,  Frankfurt am Main,  14 December 2000", 
"Willem F. Duisenberg,  President of the European Central  Bank,  Christian Noyer,  Vice-President of the European Central Bank,  Frankfurt am Main,  2 November 2000", 
"Willem F. Duisenberg,  President of the European Central  Bank,  Christian Noyer,  Vice-President of the European Central Bank,  Paris,  19 October 2000", 
"Willem F. Duisenberg,  President of the European Central  Bank,  Christian Noyer,  Vice-President of the European Central Bank,  Frankfurt am Main,  5 October 2000", 
"Willem F. Duisenberg,  President of the European Central Bank,  Christian Noyer,  Vice-President of the European Central Bank,  Frankfurt am Main,  14 September 2000", 
"Willem F. Duisenberg,  President of the European Central Bank,  Lucas Papademos,  Vice-President of the European Central Bank,  Frankfurt,  10 July 2003.", 
"Willem F. Duisenberg,  President of the European Central Bank,  Lucas Papademos,  Vice-President of the European Central Bank,    Frankfurt,  5 June 2003."
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

As you can see the text in every row follows a clear pattern, the last three words are the date. I just want to extract these three "words" (basically the date) from each row.

How would you go about it? I tried `substr` but due to the different length of each row I am not succeeding at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to select directly the last three words using the `word` function from package `stringr` (belonging to the tidyverse world)

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(word(df[,1], -3, -1), fixed("."), "")
# [1] "14 December 2000"  "2 November 2000"   "19 October 2000"   "5 October 2000"    "14 September 2000" "10 July 2003"      "5 June 2003"
```

The `str_replace_all` function is used to replace the possible dots present at the end of the strings. The `fixed` helper function indicates that `.` is an actual dot and is not a regex token.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the date using regular expressions.

```
gsub(".* (\\d+ \\w+ \\d+)\\.?$", "\\1", df[, 1])
```

The pattern  `(\\d+ \\w+ \\d+)` matches

1. one or more digits (`\\d+`), followed by
2. a space  , followed
3. one or more letters (`\\w+`), followed by
4. a space  , followed
5. one or more digits (`\\d+`).

So inside the Brackets you capture the date.
Then you replace the whole string by the date: `\\1` represents whatever was matched inside the bracket.